What frees RAM without closing Blender?
How can I free RAM in Blender without closing Blender?
My computer's RAM is about 8 Gigs. I've only used EEVEE and it's already taken up 8MB of my RAM according to the bottom statistics.

By nature of RAM, it doesn't affect performance even when full at 95%. So in your case, you don't care at all if Blender uses 0.1% of it.

@Lutzi still basically i also have other applications running in the background as well, and im worried about blender crashing due to memory being too full.
